# ruby_axlsx - Offsetting columns by a fixed number of rows (and start at the top)

Tags: ruby, axlsx

Currently I have something like

```
cell 1
cell 2
cell 3

cell 1
cell 2

cell 1
cell 2

cell 1
cell 2
cell 3
```

I want:

```
cell 1   cell 1
cell 2   cell 2
cell 3
         cell 1
cell 1   cell 2
cell 2   cell 3
```

Any way to do this without doing `ws.add_row ["cell 1", "", "", "cell1"]`? I have dynamic rows so this isn't a viable option.

Comment: Do you hope for some magic method in axlsx that will do this layout for you? Abandon all hope :) axlsx api deals in rows and cells, so you'll have to convert your dynamic something into rows of cells, which you'll then feed to axlsx.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm not expecting some sort of `#make_it_look_exactly_how_i_want` method. But some sort of `#starting_from {col: 3, row: 0}` wouldn't be so crazy.

Comment: What is the logic behind determining your desired format? How do you decide how many columns to have? How do you decide which groups of cells to put in each column? I need more information in order to provide an answer.

Comment: @TomLord First column is 6 cells wide(it it's widest), one cell of space between columns, and the second column is 3 cells wide. 2 cols only.

Comment: @PeterR I don't understand what you mean, sorry. In your example above, you have **four** "data sets", and have split them into **two** columns of equal height (6). You also have **two** blank columns between them. But will this always be the case? Is your idea to always put "data set 1" and "data set 2" into one, and the other data into a second column?

Comment: @TomLord Correct. The above data set is not identical the actual one, just a representation of what I'm trying to achieve. I would like to move the bottom half of my sections to a second column that starts n number of rows after the widest section in column 1.

Comment: @PeterR I'll ask one more time: Can you please clarify the requirements. I still don't know what you want to achieve. Your descriptions are too vague. Please edit the question to include a concise description of how the sheet should be formatted. Will you always have **four** set of data? Will you always be putting the **first two** data sets into column 1? If you have different-length data sets, how will you determine which sets to put in each column? (Are you actually "splitting the data in half, by total length"?)

Comment: As Sergio said initially, I cannot write a `format_to_look_pretty` method without knowing what that format is actually supposed to be!

Comment: @TomLord Everything from row 35, col 0 and down, I want to move to row 0, col 8.

Comment: ...And you will **always** have *exactly* 35 rows? I thought you said the data is dynamic. This is still not a proper description of your problem. Voting to close, sorry.

Comment: @TomLord I give you a dynamic explanation of what I want, and it's not exact enough. I give an exact explanation with exact numbers and row, and it's not dynamic enough for you. I don't think you know what explanation you're looking for. It's not that hard to understand what I'm looking for. I'm looking to split my single column into two columns at the rough halfway point. In this case, row 35.

Comment: *"I'm looking to split my single column into two columns at the rough halfway point."* -- This is exactly the question I'm asking for clarification on!! What do you mean by "roughly the halfway point"??? How do you choose the cutoff point? (And will you **always** split the column into two? Even if it's very short or very long?)

Comment: For example, *maybe* (???!!) your logic is "columns should be no more than 40 rows; split at the end of each data set". Or *maybe* (???!!) the logic is "each column should contain no more than two data sets, regardless of length". Or *maybe* (???!!) the logic should be "split the data exactly in half, even if it cuts through the middle of a data set". .....